# Vertically align logo with button in Bootstrap 4 navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I create in Bootstrap 4 so that the button on mobile view aligns nicely vertically? Logo should be on the left, button on the right.
Using minimal markup. Do I even have to set `order: 2` on button to align it to the right? Also `align-items: content` doesn't work for some reason for vertically aligning.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egypoe

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-toggleable-md navbar-affix py-4">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between hidden-lg-up">

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler2" aria-controls="navbarToggler2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img class="logo img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler2">

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <li class="menu-item">Link 1</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Link 2</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Link 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 183px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .navbar-toggler {
    order: 2;
    border: 0;
  }
  .d-flex {
    align-items: center;
  }
}

ul li {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Please, enter your full code as in the code does not sends an output to console,

Comment: Image for some reason doesn't show but it is visible when resized to smaller screen (for which I am asking). On desktop the layout seems fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `align items: content` isn't working for vertical centering is because the button has a `align-self` property that is overriding it. You can fix this by adding `align-self: auto` or even `align-self: center` to the button.

You do need `order: 2` on the button to change the order in the DOM. I mean, there's other ways to do it with positioning and floats, but this is the easiest for flex layouts.